# POST fails with javascript but succeeds with form on IIS hosted webpage

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, handler, iis-8

I'm extremely stuck on an issue: I have a very basic webpage hosted on my server's IIS, which has a form consisting on 2 fields:
1. Users
2. Message

I have an API that allows me to send the message to a single user, so initially the webpage was just a form with a post method and action to the API and it worked perfectly. But the idea behind the webpage is to enable bulk sending to all the users listed on the Users field, so to do this I created a simple javascript that's supposed to do it, but when I try to post even for a single user from the java script I get the "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed" error. I've been fiddling around with event handlers on my IIS Manager but the best I've been able to accomplish is to get the webpage to reload as a blank page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my JS with a URL to a request bin (was using it for testing):

```
function sendMsg(){
    console.log("laca a");
    var recipients = document.getElementById('pageto').value;
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
    var pageto= recipients.split(",");
    var responses = "";
    var de="";
    var st="";
    for (index = 0; index < pageto.length; index++) {
        alert("Sending to " + pageto[index]);
        try{
        $.post("https://en6ynqbviq1xe.x.pipedream.net/",
        {
           pageto:pageto[index],
           msg:msg,
           submit:""
        },
        function(data,status){
                de = data.value;
                st = status;
            responses.concat(data," ",status," \n");
        });
        }
        catch(err){
        responses.concat(" ",err," \n");
        }
    }
    alert("done");
}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\style.css">
  <script src="JS\main2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" method="post"> 
    <h3>Bulk message</h3>
    <h4>Enter Users and your message</h4>
      <input id="pageto" name="pageto" placeholder="User1, User2, User3" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
      <textarea maxlength="160" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Type your message here...." tabindex="2" required></textarea>

      <button name="submit" type="submit" onClick="sendMsg()" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>'
```

Please, i'm losing my mind over this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to send the  [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request to the server. It return the 405 error.

The CORS means it will allow Ajax calls to services in the same domain as the HTML page.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to add below config in your server's web.config server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webserver>
    <httpprotocol>
      <customheaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="domain" />
      </customheaders>
    </httpprotocol>
  </system.webserver>
</configuration>
```